# Where does the Lazarus Chrome extension store its database?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, database, session-restore, autosave, lazarus

[Lazarus'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery) [website](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) [is down](http://isup.me/http://getlazarus.com), so I can't look this up. Where in Linux should I look to find its SQLite database of saved forms?

Comment: [Not that](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Databases) Lazarus.

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/lazarus-a-must-have-firefox-add-on-to-save-your-form-data/) on Windows 

"""This database is stored within the default Profile (`C:\Documents and Settings\<username.\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profile`) folder in the system.""" Can't find it in `~/.config/google-chrome/` on my Linux machine though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lazarus website can be found in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221093128/http://getlazarus.com/FAQ), and the FAQ says the database is an SQLite database in one of the following directories:

Windows 7: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno_0`

Ubuntu: `~/.config/chromium/Default/databases/chrome-extension_loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno_0`

Mac OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno_0`

On my Fedora machine, it was the directory `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno_0/`